# Merge with pandas creating new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe that has multiple references to another (as if it was foreign keys in SQL) and so, I want to merge them, in a way that I can have all the info from the second dataframe in the first. Something like the following, remember using pandas in python.

```
df1:                        df2:                          

    pk    fk1   fk2         pk    att1   att2
0: 0001    2     3          1     'aa'   'bb'
1: 0002    2     -          2     'ab'   'ba'
2: 0003    1     3          3     'ab'   'bb'
```

And what I pretend to merge is in a single table like:

```
df3:                                                  

    pk    fk1   fk2   att1_1   att1_2   att2_1   a2t2_2
0: 0001    2     3     'ab'     'ba'     'ab'    'bb'
1: 0002    2     -     'ab'     'ba'      -       -
2: 0003    1     3     'aa'     'bb'     'ab'    'bb'
```

The merge option (as I am using it at the moment) is not giving me any result. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what df3 is, or is supposed to be.  Why are there two versions of `att1` instead of one?  Are you just trying to do:  `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` ?

Comment: df3 is supposed to be a new dataframe, that has the whole data in the same table.

att1 and att2 have 2 different versions, that is because for each fk in df1 there is one att1 and att2 in df2, so you have for fk1 the columns att1_1 and att1_2, and for fk2 you have att2_1 and att2_2

Comment: OK, so you want to match on 'fk1' to 'pk' AND 'fk2' to 'pk'.  It's best to put that in the question itself.  Anyway, start with `df1.merge(df2,left_on='fk1',right_on='pk')`, but you'll need to change 'fk2' column to fix the `-`, which may be your problem.  Either make it a special valued int like '99999' for example, or a NaN although then it becomes a float and might have problems matching to 'pk'.  Anyway, try to get pk/fk1/fk2 to be all the same type and it should be a straightforward merge.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and produces the table you're looking for:

```
df3=df1.join(df2.set_index('pk'),on='fk1').join(df2.set_index('pk'),on='fk2',lsuffix="_1",rsuffix="_2").fillna('-')
```

which gives:

```
     pk  fk1 fk2 att1_1 att2_1 att1_2 att2_2
0  0001    2   3     ab     ba     ab     bb
1  0002    2   -     ab     ba      -      -
2  0003    1   3     aa     bb     ab     bb
```

Here it is a little bit easier to read and only filling na's on the columns added through the join:

```
#set the index to pk on df2 for the join to work
df2.set_index('pk',inplace=True)

#join fk1 of df1 to index of df2, then again for fk2
#since there is column overlap you can assign your desired suffixes
df3=df1.join(df2,on='fk1').join(df2,on='fk2',lsuffix="_1",rsuffix="_2")

#fill na in the last 4 columns with '-' since they could not join
df3[df3.columns[-4:]]=df3[df3.columns[-4:]].fillna('-')
```